# RegLoadAppKey working fine on 32-bit OS, failing on 64-bit OS, even if both processes are 32-bit

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I'm using .NET 4 and the new [RegistryKey.FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780891.aspx) call so I can take the hKey I get from opening a software registry file with [RegLoadAppKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724886.aspx) and operate on it with the existing managed API.

I thought at first it was just a matter of a busted DllImport and my call had an invalid type in the params or a missing MarshalAs or whatever, but looking at other registry functions and their DllImport declarations (for instance, on pinvoke.net), I don't see what else to try (I've had hKey returned as both int and IntPtr, both worked on 32-bit OS and fail on 64-bit OS)

I've got it down to as simple a repro case as I can - it just tries to create a 'random' subkey then write a value to it. It works fine on my Win7 x86 box and fails on Win7 x64 and 2008 R2 x64, even when it's still a 32-bit process, even run from a 32-bit cmd prompt.  EDIT: It also fails in the same way if it's a 64-bit process.
EDIT: it works fine if the file passed in is empty - the problem case is for the existing software registry hive.  I extracted 'bare' software registry hive files from 2008 r2 (x64) and WHS v1 (x86) iso's and both have the same problem.

on Win7 x86:

```
INFO: Running as Admin in 32-bit process on 32-bit OS
Was able to create Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx\a95b1bbf-7a04-4707-bcca-6aee6afbfab7 and write a value under it
```

on Win7 x64, as 32-bit:

```
INFO: Running as Admin in 32-bit process on 64-bit OS

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key '\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx\ce6d5ff6-c3af-47f7-b3dc-c5a1b9a3cd22' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey)
   at LoadAppKeyAndModify.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

on Win7 x64, as 64-bit:

```
INFO: Running as Admin in 64-bit process on 64-bit OS

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key '\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx\43bc857d-7d07-499c-8070-574d6732c130' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)
   at LoadAppKeyAndModify.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

source:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INFO: Running as {0} in {1}-bit process on {2}-bit OS",
            new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) ? "Admin" : "Normal User",
            Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 64 : 32,
            Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? 64 : 32);

        if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Need 1 argument - path to the software hive file on disk");
        }
        string softwareHiveFile = Path.GetFullPath(args[0]);
        if (File.Exists(softwareHiveFile) == false)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Specified file does not exist: " + softwareHiveFile);
        }

        // pick a random subkey so it doesn't already exist
        var existingKeyPath = @"Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion";
        var keyPathToCreate = @"RunOnceEx\" + Guid.NewGuid();
        var completeKeyPath = Path.Combine(existingKeyPath, keyPathToCreate);
        var hKey = RegistryNativeMethods.RegLoadAppKey(softwareHiveFile);
        using (var safeRegistryHandle = new SafeRegistryHandle(new IntPtr(hKey), true))
        using (var appKey = RegistryKey.FromHandle(safeRegistryHandle))
        using (var currentVersionKey = appKey.OpenSubKey(existingKeyPath, true))
        {
            if (currentVersionKey == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Specified file is not a well-formed software registry hive: " + softwareHiveFile);
            }

            using (var randomSubKey = currentVersionKey.CreateSubKey(keyPathToCreate))
            {
                randomSubKey.SetValue("foo", "bar");
                Console.WriteLine("Was able to create {0} and write a value under it", completeKeyPath);
            }
        }
    }
}

internal static class RegistryNativeMethods
{
    [Flags]
    public enum RegSAM
    {
        AllAccess = 0x000f003f
    }

    private const int REG_PROCESS_APPKEY = 0x00000001;

    // approximated from pinvoke.net's RegLoadKey and RegOpenKey
    // NOTE: changed return from long to int so we could do Win32Exception on it
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int RegLoadAppKey(String hiveFile, out int hKey, RegSAM samDesired, int options, int reserved);

    public static int RegLoadAppKey(String hiveFile)
    {
        int hKey;
        int rc = RegLoadAppKey(hiveFile, out hKey, RegSAM.AllAccess, REG_PROCESS_APPKEY, 0);

        if (rc != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(rc, "Failed during RegLoadAppKey of file " + hiveFile);
        }

        return hKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work when you run it as a 64bit process on the 64bit machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up with opening a support case with Microsoft Support - the problem is specific to 1) the hives that ship on the install media for recent versions of Windows and 2) RegLoadAppKey as an API.  Switching over to RegLoadKey/RegUnLoadKey instead worked fine for the exact same files (in the same process, even), and since the bug in RegLoadAppKey is unlikely to get fixed (let alone soon) to deal with those specific files, I just switched to RegLoadKey/RegUnLoadKey instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following link should be helpful in this scenario:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx#64mig_topic5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. can you elaborate more please?